# How MySQL tables are opened? table_definition_cache, table_open_cache, .frm files and Data Dictionary: How are they related?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, innodb, data-dictionary

MySQL version: 5.7 Machine: Ubuntu 20.04

Recently, we were analysing the performance issues that can occur when increasing the number of tables in a schema. And during this, we came across 4 system variables that have impact on the performance: **table_open_cache**, **open_files_limit**, **table_definition_cache** and the **Dictionary memory allocated** from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Here's what we know:

1. **table_open_cache**: The maximum number of tables that can be open concurrently across all sessions.
2. **open_files_limit**: Maximum number of files that can be open in the mysqld process.
3. **table_definition_cache**: The maximum number of tables whose metadata can be stored in memory, without having to use file descriptors to read the .frm files.
4. **Dictionary Memory Allocated**: The amount of memory that is allocated in the innodb dictionary. There is no limit and it keeps increasing.

With these information in mind, we decided to create 100,000 tables in a schema and run a loop to read these tables using the `SELECT * FROM tablename` command.

Here is the code and the stats we arrived at:

```
int num = 1;                
long currTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i=1;i<=100000;i++)
{
    String tableName = table + i;
    st.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName + "");
    if(i%5000==0)
    {
        printDictMemory(st,num++);
        long diff= System.currentTimeMillis()-currTime;
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,i +"tables. "+diff+"ms");
        currTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }               
}
```

The **printDictMemory()** method runs the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command and prints the dictionary memory allocated at that time.

Stats:

System variables: **table_open_cache**=2000, **open_files_limit**=5000, **table_definition_cache**=1400

```
tables  time(ms)    Dictionary memory
    5000    8228ms  105886810
    10000   9008ms  168551811
    15000   9385ms  231221811
    20000   8181ms  174365726
    25000   7376ms  237035726
    30000   6491ms  299705726
    35000   6215ms  362375726
    40000   7087ms  425045726
    45000   6422ms  276819109
    50000   6216ms  339489109
    55000   6720ms  402159109
    60000   7691ms  464829109
    65000   8225ms  527499109
    70000   6128ms  590169109
    75000   6359ms  377517265
    80000   6570ms  440187265
    85000   7913ms  502857265
    90000   9245ms  565527265
    95000   9490ms  352261255
    100000  6202ms  414931256
```

The file descriptors count during the process did not go beyond 2030.

So, here are the questions that I need answers for:

1. Why is the Dictionary memory not constantly increasing?
2. What is happening when the Dictionary memory reduces in size?
3. I took stats by setting the **table_open_cache=3000**. But still, the file descriptors count stayed at 2020-2030. Why are the file descriptors not increasing in number?
4. We know that, in a File-per-Table tablespace, .frm files contain the table_definition and the .ibd files contain the table data. In the `/proc/PID/fd` is where we took the File descriptor count from. Here, even while reading the table for the first time, only .ibd files were read. No .frm files were listed. Why?
5. Finally, Here's what we think happens when we open a MySQL table:

The server first checks if the number of tables opened is less than the value of the **table_open_cache** variable. If it's not, MySQL uses an LRU algorithm to remove the least recently used table. Now, when a table is read, the InnoDB engine checks the Data Dictionary if the table definition is present or not. If not, it checks the **table_definition_cache** in the server layer. If it's not present in the table_defintion_cache, MySQL uses File Descriptors to read the .frm and then the .ibd files. It then adds the table definition to the **table_definition_cache** in the server layer and also to the **Data Dictionary** in the InnoDB storage engine layer. So, next time when the table needs to be read, InnoDB can simply get the table definition from the Data Dictionary cache.

Is the above flow correct? If not, How does MySQL open the tables? Please share your knowledge on the same.

**EDIT:**

w.r.t Wilson's comment, here are the below stats:

**Global VARIABLES and STATUS initially:**

[image]

**Stats:**

[image]

Thank you for the patience. Would definitely appreciate your answers.

Comment: MySQL implements *caches( for open files, tables, and so forth. It manages those caches by  removing stale entries by closing tables and files. It can always reopen an object it has closed if some user session needs it. Your test tries to overflow the caches, but MySQL stays ahead of the situation.

Comment: Could you enhance your output by adding results of SELECT NOW(); when the calculations are triggered for each 5,000 tables?  This will give us a sense of wall clock time for your environment.

Comment: Another 2 requests, please.  In your logger.log file, log the limits to include from SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES results of table_open_cache, innodb_open_files, table_open_cache_instances, table_definition_cache, open file limits discovered at beginning of your routine, Add at each 5000 output of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'open%_table%'; .  Today we only see Open_table_definitions, Open_tables, Opened_table_definitions and Opened_tables.  Thank you for considering this request.  If you could share the supporting functions, this would be a GREAT utility for general use.

Comment: Hi Wilson. Took the stats for the same and updated the post. Please look into it and share your insights.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a direct answer, but related.)

May I suggest that the `STATUS` values `Table_open_cache_hits` and `_misses` are useful for computing misses/second (using `Uptime`) and percentage of misses.  These formulas give clues as to whether `table_open_cache` is set properly.  Alas, it does not say how much to increase or decrease that setting.

You might run your experiment again, while watching

```
Table_open_cache_hits / Uptime
Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses)
```

I "recommend" that the latter be kept under 3%.  (This is one of a few hundred checks I make when reviewing `VARIABLES` and `STATUS` for a system.